# Comparar campos de um formulário

Tags: javascript

Tenho um formulário com os campos abaixo. Preciso comparar o ano do campo `select` com ano da data informada via JavaScript, sendo que o ano da data informada tem que ser idêntico ao ano escolhido, mas ainda não obtive êxito.

```
<label for="ano_licenca"><strong>ANO DA LICENCA</strong></label>
<select name="ano_licenca" id="ano_licenca" class="form-control">
    <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select> <br><br>

<label for="data_emissao"><strong>DATA EMISSAO *</strong></label>
<input type="date" name="data_emissao" id="data_emissao" class="form-control" onblur="comparadataano()" autofocus/><br><br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function comparadataano()
    {
        var ano_licenca = document.getElementById("ano_licenca");
        var data_emissao = document.getElementById("data_emissao");

        if (data_emissao.value > ano_licenca.value || data_emissao.value < ano_licenca.value) {
            alert("ERRO! O ANO INFORMADO, NAO ESTAR COM O MESMO ANO DA DATA DE EMISSAO");
            ano_licenca = document.getElementById('ano_licenca').value = '';
            data_emissao = document.getElementById('data_emissao').value = '';

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Veja o exemplo funcionando:**

```js
function comparaDataAno() {
  var ano_licenca = document.getElementById("ano_licenca").value;
  var data_emissao = document.getElementById("data_emissao").value;
  var data = data_emissao.substr(0,4); // pega só o ano

  if (ano_licenca != data) {
  alert("ERRO! O ANO INFORMADO, NAO ESTA COM O MESMO ANO DA DATA DE EMISSAO");
  } else {
  alert("Datas válidas");
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="ano_licenca"><strong>ANO DA LICENCA</strong></label>
<select name="ano_licenca" id="ano_licenca" class="form-control">
  <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>

<label for="data_emissao"><strong>DATA EMISSAO *</strong></label>
<input type="date" name="data_emissao" id="data_emissao" class="form-control" onblur="comparaDataAno()"/>
```

> VC precisa melhorar algumas coisa no seu código:
>
> **1- Sempre colocar o nome da função com `camelcase` ou usar `(_)` para uma melhor legibilidade**.
>
> **2- O seu `if` não precisa testar as condiçõe daquela maneira, com um simples `(!=)` vc diminui o código**.
>
> **3- O `autofocus` não é necessário pois primeiro vc quer que o `select` seja preenchido**.

Comment: Obrigado amigo! valeu pela força